# Fullscreen application over two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, fullscreen, gnome3, ubuntu-unity

I have a dual-head setup running Ubuntu 13.04 with Gnome/Unity (the default desktop). What I'm trying to achieve is to display Firefox in "fullscreen" mode (e.g. hit F11 after it is launched), and have Firefox be displayed as a single window across both screens. I've dug every possible setting in Gnome and can't find out how to have fullscreen span across the whole desktop.

I have an nVidia video card with the latest driver (313.26) installed, and TwinView enabled. I tried messing with the "NoTwinViewXineramaInfo" option but to no avail.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible on Gnome/Unity? If so, how must I configure the desktop to achieve it?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want?  SuperUser will be `|` split right down the middle between the two monitors.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, the behavior you describe is exactly what I want

Comment: nVidia appears to have something called SurroundView that will achieve what you want.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: SurroundView is actually a technology from ATI, not nVidia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATI_Hybrid_Graphics#SurroundView

Comment: I guess I got them backwards.  There's a corresponding technology that nVidia offers, if you look for it.

Comment: Yeah, it's the embedded Xinerama in TwinView, but like I mentionned in the original question, I tried it and it doesn't work. I think Gnome overrides it.